# How to solve $ \sqrt{x^2 +\sqrt{4x^2 +\sqrt{16x^2+ \sqrt{64x^2+\dotsb} } } } =5\,$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, radicals, nested-radicals

How to find $x$ in:
$$
\sqrt{x^2 +\sqrt{4x^2 +\sqrt{16x^2+ \sqrt{64x^2+\dotsb} } }  } =5
$$

Comment: Shouldn't the RHS be a function of $x$?

Comment: I interpreted the question as showing that the two sides of the equation are equal. I think that @TitoPiezasIII's interpretation was more to the point of the question. My apologies

Comment: @ClementC. Yeah, that makes more sense.

Comment: It seems for any positive real number $x$, we have, $$
\sqrt{x^2 +\sqrt{4x^2 +\sqrt{16x^2+ \sqrt{64x^2+\dotsb} } }  } =x+1\tag1
$$ Hence the solution to the OP's problem is $x=4$. However, it remains to prove the general case.

Answer (score 14):

**Hint:** $~x+1=\sqrt{x^2+2x+1}=\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{4x^2+4x+1}}=\ldots~$ Can you take it from here ? :-$)$

Comment: You could put the development of the equation please

Comment: How is this any different from $x + 2 = \sqrt {x^2 + 4x+4} = \sqrt{x^2 + \sqrt{16x²+32x+16}} = \sqrt {x^2 + \sqrt{4x^2 + \sqrt{\ldots}}}$ ?

Comment: How do you get from the third to the fourth, @mercio? (It is different as Lucian's solution does get the $1,4,16,64,\dots$, while yours gets $1,16,?,\dots$)

Comment: @susy: It's not that difficult, $$\begin{aligned}x+1&=\sqrt{x^2+(2x+1)}\\&=\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{(2x+1)^2}}\\& =\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{4x^2+(4x+1)}}\\&=\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{4x^2+\sqrt{(4x+1)^2}}}\\& =\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{4x^2+\sqrt{16x^2+(8x+1)}}}\end{aligned}$$ and so on.

Comment: @mercio Because the degree of the terms in your RHS will increase without bounds (e.g., the ldots there includes a term $144x^4$, since you're taking an expression that square roots to $12x^2+32x+16$).  Showing convergence even in the 'right' case is definitely non-trivial, but your attempted matching expression should much more clearly diverge.

Comment: Nice solution. However there seems to be some ambiguity the way the expression in the question can be interpreted (i.e. in what we take as the initial seed for the recursion). For example it looks like taking $x=0$ should give $0$ as the result and not $1$ as we get with this procedure.

Comment: Sorry, I missed so explanation.
I speak Spanish and there are things I do not know, what is LHS and RHS?

Comment: left hand side, right hand side: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sides_of_an_equation

Comment: @Winther: Notice that each nested radical ends in $1,$ not $0.$ So if we carefully and rigorously define the infinitely-nested radical in question as a **limit** of partially-nested radicals, the result will indeed be $1,$ and not $0.$

Comment: @susy: My explanation is as simple as it gets. Continue the procedure to $\sqrt{(8x+1)^2} = \sqrt{64x^2+16x+1}$ and you'll get the pattern.

Comment: ok with LHS and RHS ... language problems

Comment: @mercio: Maybe you can delete your comment? I think it is confusing Susy.  :)

Comment: @Winther: The expression in question creates no problems for positive values of *x* or *a*.

Comment: Now, I have answers and algebraic substitutions, until then it was fine but looked equation expressed recursively.
With that solution should I be me, there are things that escape me, if I explain them in more detail please ...

Comment: I upvoted  this answer but I do not think it is correct!

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal then why on Earth would you upvote it?!

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: What makes you suspect that ?

Comment: @ClementC.: Relax!  It is not a big deal!!

Comment: It's just... puzzling. Like saying "I am vegan and lactose-intolerant but just ordered 500 lbs of cheese."

Comment: @Lucian: I will be reviewing this later!  This is not a big issue!

Comment: @Winther Exactly!  There are so many of these posted questions that fall into the same category - ill-posed nested operations with no initial seed.  Glad you posted your comment!  +1   - Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes I have also seen many questions where this issue is a real problem, but as Lucian cleared up above there is not a big problem in this particular case as long as the seed is stricktly positive. The only issue is at $x=0$ when the seed is $0$ which gives $f(0)=0$ instead of $f(0)=1$.

Comment: @Winther Yes, that is true here.  But your comment, I believe, might help others on the site understand that there is a very important consideration (often ignored) when dealing with these types of "recursive" relationships.  So, well done!  - Mark

Comment: @ClementC. On the "vegan" comment ... now that was funny!!  - Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV I like cheese. :)

Comment: @ClementC. Very Gouda ... see what I did there?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Any progress in your review?

Comment: @Lucian: It is correct.