# Determine $x$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{1+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2…+\sqrt{x^n}}}} = 2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, nested-radicals

Find the value of $x$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{1+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2…+\sqrt{x^n}}}} = 2$

I tried getting rid of square roots and got $(...((9-x)^2-x^2)^2-...)^2-x^n = 0$ which I don't think helped. Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you mean for the limit to be as $n \to \infty$ instead of $x \to \infty$?

Comment: I'm sorry, yes, I meant that. Edited

Comment: Answer is 4. Not sure how to prove it though.

Comment: As Lucian pointed out, from [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1657495/) we have the more general equality,$$\sqrt{y^2+\sqrt{4y^2+\sqrt{4^2y^2+\sqrt{4^3y^2+\dots}}}}=y+1$$ Let $y=1$, $$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{4^2+\sqrt{4^3+\dots}}}}=2$$ So the answer to your question is $x=4$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me describe a sketch of proof that $x=4$.

A. Observe that if $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+\cdots\sqrt{x^n}}}}$, then $f$ is strictly increasing.

B. We shall show that $f(4)=2$, and hence $x=4$ is the unique answer.

$B_1.$ Fix $m\in\mathbb N$ and show that, for $n=m,m-1,m-2,\cdots$ (induction backwards) 
$$
2^n<\sqrt{4^n+\sqrt{4^{n+1}+\cdots\sqrt{4^{m-1}+\sqrt{4^m}}}}<2^n+1,
$$
while
$$
\sqrt{4^n+\sqrt{4^{n+1}+\cdots\sqrt{4^{m-1}+\sqrt{4^m}+1}}}=2^n+1.
$$

$B_2.$ Next estimate the difference
$$
(2^n+1)-
\sqrt{4^n+\sqrt{4^{n+1}+\cdots\sqrt{4^{m-1}+\sqrt{4^m}}}} \\
=\sqrt{4^n+\sqrt{4^{n+1}+\cdots\sqrt{4^{m-1}+\sqrt{4^m}+1}}}-
\sqrt{4^n+\sqrt{4^{n+1}+\cdots\sqrt{4^{m-1}+\sqrt{4^m}}}} \\
=\frac{\sqrt{4^{n+1}+\cdots\sqrt{4^{m-1}+\sqrt{4^m}+1}}-
\sqrt{4^{n+1}+\cdots\sqrt{4^{m-1}+\sqrt{4^m}}}}{\sqrt{4^n+\sqrt{4^{n+1}+\cdots\sqrt{4^{m-1}+\sqrt{4^m}+1}}}+
\sqrt{4^n+\sqrt{4^{n+1}+\cdots\sqrt{4^{m-1}+\sqrt{4^m}}}}} \\
<\frac{{\sqrt{4^{n+1}+\cdots\sqrt{4^{m-1}+\sqrt{4^m}+1}}-
\sqrt{4^{n+1}+\cdots\sqrt{4^{m-1}+\sqrt{4^m}}}}}{2\cdot 2^n} \\
<\cdots<\frac{(\sqrt{4^m}+1)-\sqrt{4^m}}{2^{m-n}\cdots 2^{n+(n+1)+\cdots+(m-1)}}=2^{-\frac{(m-n)(n+m+1)}{2}}
$$
Thus
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\sqrt{4^n+\sqrt{4^{n+1}+\cdots\sqrt{4^{m-1}+\sqrt{4^m}}}}=2^n+1.
$$
For $n=0$ we have
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{4+\cdots\sqrt{4^{m-1}+\sqrt{4^m}}}}=2^0+1=2.
$$

Comment: I have corrected it now!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Pretend that there's an extra $+1$ at the next-to-last level. Then $$4^{n-1}+\sqrt{4^n}+1~=~2^{2(n-1)}+2^n+1~=~2^{2(n-1)}+2\cdot2^{n-1}+1~=~(2^{n-1}+1)^2.$$ Can you see what happens ? :-$)~$ Now, as $n\to\infty,$ the numerical influence gained by adding that extra $+1$ at the top level tends towards $0.$

Comment: [A similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1657495).

Answer (score -4):

$$A = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{x+\sqrt {x^2+\sqrt{x^3+\sqrt{x^4+\sqrt{x^5+...}}}}}} = 2$$

$$A = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{x\left(1+\sqrt {1+\sqrt{x^1+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^3+...}}}}\right)}} = 2$$

$$A = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{x(1+A)}} = 2,A =2$$

$$ \sqrt{1+\sqrt{3x}} = 2$$

$$ 1+\sqrt{3x} = 4$$

$$ \sqrt{3x} = 3$$

$$ x = 3$$

Comment: I am afraid that the second line is incorrect.

Comment: The sequence should be $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}, \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2x}},  \sqrt{1+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+x\sqrt{x}}}}, \sqrt{1+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^{3}+x^{2}}}}},\ldots$ and the above method doesn't work.

Comment: no, because A is a limit that has a finite response.

Comment: Check with the numerical values:$x=3$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(1%2Bsqrt(3%2Bsqrt(3%5E2%2Bsqrt(3%5E3%2Bsqrt(3%5E4))))) and $x=4$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(1%2Bsqrt(4%2Bsqrt(4%5E2%2Bsqrt(4%5E3%2Bsqrt(4%5E4)))))

Comment: I have also tried with $x=3.5$  [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(1%2Bsqrt(3.5%2Bsqrt(3.5%5E2%2Bsqrt(3.5%5E3%2Bsqrt(3.5%5E4)))))) and $x=4.001$ [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(1%2Bsqrt(4%2Bsqrt(4%5E2%2Bsqrt(4%5E3%2Bsqrt(4%5E4)))))),you are correct answer is $x=4$.